# How to find text-box in GridView using Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to get access and find text-box in GridView using javascript but i am getting an error: 'The name txt_UID' does not exist in the current context'.  Everything worked fine when my text-box was outside of the GridView.  Here is my text-box in the gridview and my gridview is called GridView1:

```
 <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="150px" HeaderText="User Assigned">
    <ItemTemplate>  
     <asp:TextBox ID="txt_UID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UID")%>'
        CssClass="AutoCompleteTextBox" Width="130px" BackColor="LightGoldenrodYellow"></asp:TextBox>
       </ItemTemplate>
         <ItemStyle Width="150px" />
         </asp:TemplateField>
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
  <script type ="text/javascript">
        function setAutoComplete() {
            var textBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName("AutoCompleteTextBox");
            for (var i = 0; i < textBoxes.length; i++) {
                addAutoComplete(textBoxes[i].id);
            }
        }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function addAutoComplete(textBoxId) {
        $("#" + textBoxId).autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Service.asmx/GetUserNames") %>',
                    data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.split('-')[0],
                                val: item.split('-')[1]
                            }
                        }))
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            },
            select: function (e, i) {
                $("#<%=hfUserId.ClientID %>").val(i.item.val);
            },
            minLength: 1
        });
    };
```

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () { setAutoComplete(); });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Gridview` will be rendered as `Table` and your control will be contained in `cell` of table. You can give a try to following.

```
<script type=”text/javascript”>
$(document).ready(function(){
tblTable=document.getElementById(‘<<Client ID of the GridView>>’);
Cell=tblTable.rows[i].cells[j];//i and j are locations of that cell.
FirstControl = Cell.childNodes[0];
});
</script>
```

replace `<<Client ID of the GridView>>` with id of your `GridView`

Comment: Thanks, i am not a javascript person but how can i apply your solution to the javascript code that i posted?  I need to use that code please.. thanks

Comment: Imad, i am not sure where to put this <body onload="findControl()">
</body>?? could you clarify please?  thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `GridView` creates a `TextBox` on each row. There is no "txt_UID" control outside of the `GridView`. That is what your error message is telling you.

Your `JavaScript` function is designed to work with one `TextBox`. I imagine you want the AutoComplete to work on ALL `TextBox` controls in the `GridView`.

My suggestion would be to change the `JavaScript` function to take a parameter with the `TextBox` ID and then add a `CSS class` to each `TextBox`, and finally make a wrapper `JavaScript` function that will enumerate the `TextBox` controls using `getElementsByClassName`, and call that wrapper function on `DOM ready`.

Here's what it will look like:

Add CSS class to the TextBoxes:

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="150px" HeaderText="User Name">
    <ItemTemplate>  
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_UID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UID")%>'
            CssClass="AutoCompleteTextBox" Width="130px" BackColor="LightGoldenrodYellow"></asp:TextBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle Width="150px" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

New `JavaScript` function:

```
function setAutoComplete()
{
    var textBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName("AutoCompleteTextBox");
    for (var i = 0; i < textBoxes.length; i++)
    {
        addAutoComplete(textBoxes[i].id);
    }
}
```

Next, make your other `JavaScript` into a function that takes a parameter (the id):

```
function addAutoComplete(textBoxId) {
    $("#" + textBoxId).autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Service.asmx/GetUserNames") %>',
                data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.split('-')[0],
                            val: item.split('-')[1]
                        }
                    }))
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (e, i) {
            $("#<%=hfUserId.ClientID %>").val(i.item.val);
        },
        minLength: 1
    });
};
```

Finally, your on ready code changes to just call the wrapper function you created:

```
$(document).ready(function () { setAutoComplete(); });
```

**Bonus: Here's a way to do it with jQuery only:**

(just requires the CSS class on the TextBoxes)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.each($(".AutoCompleteTextBox"), function (i, textBox) {
        textBox.autocomplete( /* your code */);
    })
});
```

Comment: thanks David, do i need to change the textBoxId into txt_UID? because that is the id for my text-box thanks.

Comment: No because the way my code works is that textBoxId is the real ID of the textBox, which the wrapper function, setAutoComplete, retrieves using the built-in JavaScript document.getElementsByClassName() method. Basically my code does not care what the ID is of your textbox - it uses the new CSS class I added to obtain a reference to all of the textboxes in the GridView (as long as you don't put that css class on any other controls or elements).

Comment: Remember you don't have ONE textbox... you have a textbox in EACH row of the gridview. This is generated by asp.net for you as HTML elements, each one with a unique ID. The only place that "txt_UID" has any meaning is inside the GridView. There are ways to access it in .net (using FindControl method) but the way I did it is actually simpler, I think.

Comment: that is right, i am making the changes now and testing it.  will let you know soon.  thanks

Comment: @moe: One more thing I had a bug in my jQuery -- changed `$(textBoxId)`  to `$("#" + textBoxId)`, it will work now.

Comment: okay let me try that because i had some issues before. thanks

Comment: David, i am getting this error:Error: Object doesn't support this property or method and it is failing when setAutoComplete() function is called.  I updated my initial post so please look at it see what am i doing wrong.  thanks

Comment: Are you sure the autocomplete plugin is loaded? It would seem that is the issue; calling autocomplete() before plugin is loaded would fail

Comment: i was not using any autocomplete plugin before but i just downloaded and used it but still failing for the same thing

Comment: I tested this with simple JS functions, like setting click method and then calling it and it worked; so I think the issue is with the autocomplete. Was your autocomplete script working before?

Comment: yes it was working fine before without using the autocomplete plugin but the only difference is my text box was outside of the gridview

Comment: Ok possibly you already had the autocomplete plugin. I think what is likely happening is that autocomplete (not a standard method of HTML Input element, i.e, your TextBox) is not available yet when this code is being called. Try this: comment out the `$(document).ready()` code, and at the very bottom of your page, add a <script> tag and just call `setAutoComplete();` from it, see if that works?

Comment: You'll need to play with it some more to sort it out. Without seeing your full code/page (or a minimized version that shows this problem) it's hard to help from here.

Comment: thanks David, i tried and it did not work but i will keep playing with it

Answer (score 0):

you can use name attribute and the grid id to find it:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_UID" name="mytextbox" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UID")%>'
        Width="130px" BackColor="LightGoldenrodYellow"></asp:TextBox>
```

the javascript part:

```
$("#<%=MyGrid.ClientID %>[name=mytextbox]").autocomplete({});
```